# Why would I care about "potential for downward pressure on the price of loaned securities due to short selling" when loaning securities?

Tags: united-states, stocks, loans, trading

I read in an email from Fidelity regarding their "Fidelity’s Fully Paid Lending Program":

> Keep in mind that while your securities are on loan, there is the **potential for downward pressure on the price of loaned securities due to short selling**; there are differences in the way any dividends received are taxed and in proxy voting rights; and Securities Investor Protection Corporation (SIPC) coverage does not apply.

Why would I care about "potential for downward pressure on the price of loaned securities due to short selling" when loaning securities? Is that because it increases the risk of counterparty default?

Comment: "potential for downward pressure on the price" is an idiotic way to say "the price may go down".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own a stock, do you want the price to go up or to drop?  Downward pressure isn't your friend.

Secondarily, if your shares are loaned out to a short seller and he is short on the ex-div date, the buyer of the borrowed shares receives the dividend. The share lender (you) receives payment-in-lieu (PIL) from the short seller which does not qualify for the qualified dividend rate and is taxed at ordinary income rates.